# How to map specific items within react when using json object

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a json object that I'm trying to map into a table within a react component. I'm having difficulty accessing the 'title' and the 'tooltip' from within the json object. The console log successfully shows me the entire the json object, but

```
this.props.selectedProducts.products.title
```

Which I thought would map to the 'title' part of the json data simply doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong & possibly how to correct it? Thanks in advance!

JSON:

```
selectedProducts: [
  {
    “start”: “Tue Jun 19 16:55:40 BST 2018”,
    “products”: [
      {
        “title”: “SL Primary - Alaska (Westlaw PRO™)“,
        “price”: “”
      },
      {
        “title”: “SL Ninth Circuit Primary Law (Westlaw PRO™)“,
        “price”: “”
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

React:

```
renderProducts() {
  const selected = this.props.selectedProducts;

  return this.props.selectedProducts.map((selected, i) => {
    return ( 
      <tr className="product-cells" key={i}>
        <td> {selected.title} </td>
        <td> {selected.price}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you intend to have `selectedProducts` as an array?

Comment: The json is actually coming from somewhere else so I have to use it as is @JordanS

Answer (score 0):

`selectedProducts` is an array, so you have to access the first object in the array, and map over `products`:

```
renderProducts() {
  return this.props.selectedProducts[0].products.map((selected, i) => {
    return ( 
      <tr className="product-cells" key={i}>
        <td> {selected.title} </td>
        <td> {selected.price}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use first element of your selectedProducts array as answered before or use a second map if there will be more objects:

```
  renderProducts() {
    return (
      this.props.selectedProducts.map(el =>
        el.products.map(selected => 
        <tr className="product-cells" key={selected.title}>
          <td> {selected.title} </td>
          <td> {selected.price}</td>
        </tr>)
      )
    )
  }
```

Do not use indexes as your keys. There could be some problems if you do so.